# Find all mac devices on AP

Tags: python, scapy, wifi

I try to write code with scapy in python, first step is to scan all accesses point that available and the second step is to get all mac address of the devices that connect to ap

I succeed with the first step but at the second step I do something wrong

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#part 1
# import scapy module
import scapy.all as scapy





# Extracted Packet Format 
Pkt_Info = """
---------------[ Packet Captured ]-----------------------
Subtype  : {}   
Address 1  : {} | Address 2 : {} [BSSID] 
Address 3  : {} | Address 4 : {} 
 AP   : {} [SSID]
"""


# GetAPStations Function
def GetAPStation(*args,  **kwargs):
"""
Function For Filtering Beacon Frames And Extract Access 
Point Information From Captured Packets.

"""
ap=[]
packets=[]
CliList=[]
def PacketFilter(pkt):
if pkt.haslayer(scapy.Dot11Elt) and pkt.type == 0 and pkt.subtype == 
8:
 if pkt.addr2 not in ap:
  ap.append(pkt.addr2)
  packets.append(pkt)

  print Pkt_Info.format(pkt.subtype,pkt.addr1, pkt.addr2, pkt.addr3, 
pkt.addr4,pkt.info)

scapy.sniff(prn=PacketFilter, *args, **kwargs)
return (ap, packets)

# Main Trigger
if __name__=="__main__":

# Previous Function Trigger
#
# here, iface="mon0" for Interface with monitor mode enable
#
GetAPStation(iface="mon0", timeout=60)
```

I don'n know how to filter the Dot 11 to get mac addressee in part 2, and if i need the beacon frame or the prob request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so i find can use in Dot11Qos layer 
`if  (p.haslayer(scapy.Dot11QoS) and (p.addr1!="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff") and (p.addr2== "ap mac"))  :`